# Send Data from CMD to Node.Js Server

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, connection, applet

is there a option to send data from cmd to a NodeJs server?
We have a logon script for all Computers in my company and I want them to tell my NodeJs applet who is logged on and the name of the device.

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Client side

You could use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) in cmd like that:

```
curl -d "user=%username%&computer=%computername%" -X POST "https://example.com/"
```

This example will take send the username and computername environment variables through a post request to the server.
The only problem about this is that usernames with for example spaces in them are **not** going to be encoded correctly.

So I would **recommend you to send your request through powershell**:

```
powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://example.com/' -Method POST -Body @{user=$env:username;computer=$env:computername}
```

## Server side

On the server side you then receive the post parameters 'user' and 'computer' by parsing the requested with the built in 'url' module.
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp) you can find a nice example.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could send a POST request to your server containing the data you want to send. You can do this using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/). There are a few examples of using it here: [link](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58)